# Reading external data files in gnuplot

Tags: file, plot, fortran, gnuplot

Well, this is a continuation of my previous question. As, I mentioned, the data files are produced from a Fortran code. All the data files contain two columns of data. In the Fortran code I use the `FORMAT` (2(1X,D22.16)). So, the output files look like

```
-.4515533388641104D-01 -.6842652196656712D+01
-.1381692033642749D+00 0.6762844180244199D+01
-.5741668880663318D-01 -.7891086299010933D+01
-.1051164522902431D+00 0.7758389636011907D+01
-.7574000988697732D-01 -.8180315630079706D+01
-.7939204753736680D-01 0.8167097825331970D+01
-.1003250672387262D+00 -.7865995561517515D+01
-.6006135667296913D-01 0.7987393828927278D+01
 ..................... ......................
```

This is only a small sample portion of one data file. In order to plot this data file I use

```
plot "data001.out" u 1:2 w d lc rgb 'black'
```

However, `gnuplot` fails to read the data correctly and produced this plot

[image]

The correct plot, using Mathematica program, is this

[image]

I noticed, that if I change the `FORMAT` to (2(1X,F22.16)) (in decimal form) everything is OK. Why `gnuplot` cannot read data in exponential form? Is there a way to tell the program how to read this type of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From gnuplot 4.6 manual:

"Data may be written in exponential format with the exponent preceded by the letter e or E. The fortran exponential specifiers d, D, q, and Q may also be used if the command `set datafile fortran` is in effect."

So you should put `set datafile fortran` before `plot`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What are the chances?  The question hasn't been answered for 6 hours and then we both end up working on the answer at the same time.  weird.  +1 to you!

Comment: I wonder? Quite low! +1 to you as well, we gave basically the same answer!

Comment: Yeah -- I really love getting gnuplot upvotes, but I think you beat me by about 20s, so I'll delete my answer to make sure you get the credit for it.  It only seems fair.  I'll get you next time though ;-) *(maybe)*.

Comment: @lev.tuby Thank you very much for your reply! By the way, is the version 4.6 patchlevel 1 for Windows available? I am stuck at 4.6.0 which contains several bugs ...

Comment: @mgilson: Thanks!Although I am not sure I deserve that praise. If this happens a second time I will start thinking we are in the matrix :-), but I will surely give credit to you, the answers were basically the same. 
Vaggelis_Z: you're welcome. I work only on linux, so I do not now about Windows releases. Check on www.gnuplot.info. If there is nothing there, then it is not available. Check also their demos, they are really nice.